# node.js bcrypt compare return false even just after where I hash

Tags: node.js, hash, bcrypt

I have tried this for like three hours at least and still don't get it.

my node.js app dependencis

```
"dependencies": {
  "bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
  "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
  "express": "^4.16.3",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
  "morgan": "^1.9.0",
  "mysql2": "^1.5.3",
  "sequelize": "^4.38.0",
  "sqlite": "^2.9.2"
}
```

So here is my bcrypt code:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt'))

function hashPassword (user , options) {
  if(!user.changed('password')){
    return;
  }
  const saltRounds = 10 
  return bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds).then( hash => {
    user.setDataValue('password', hash)
    bcrypt.compare(user.password, hash, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { throw (err); }
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = (sequelize, Datatypes) =>{
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email:{
      type:Datatypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    password:Datatypes.STRING
  }, {
    hooks:{
      beforeCreate: hashPassword,
      beforeUpdate: hashPassword,
      beforeSave: hashPassword
    }
  })

  User.prototype.comparePassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
  }

  return User
}
```

After I insert a new User, it return User.toJSON like below:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "email": "zxc@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2b$10$nr51wOKQaXkejeku2CnLrOtodhrJoNxLdHaHB/keNH5PbtVLdBAKe",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-14T05:02:22.764Z",
    "createdAt": "2018-07-14T05:02:22.764Z"
}
```

I think it's working well as we can see the password is hashed successfully(60 characters by the way)

But notice that I use a bcrypt.compare function after user.setDataValue

And the console.log(result) is false ...
[image]

Not even to mention every time I tried to log in, my User.prototype.comparePassword(password) always return false too!

Please help me this out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh no...I found the problem by myself

Notice here:

```
hooks:{
  beforeCreate: hashPassword,
  beforeUpdate: hashPassword,
  beforeSave: hashPassword
}
```

It hashes the password more than once...

And after I modified it ...

```
hooks:{
  beforeCreate: hashPassword,
  beforeUpdate: hashPassword
}
```

Everything works fine!